# c# Add a Column to end of CSV file

Tags: c#, csv

Trying to add a column to the end of a cvs file, which will just count up the number of lines (or can all be the same number it doesn't really mater) as the main aim is to add a new column with some data in it.

The sample CSV file I have has 3 columns with some random data in each of them.

What I have at the moment is

```
    List<string> newColumnData = new List<string>() { "D" };
    List<string> lines = File.ReadAllLines(@"C:/CSV/test.csv").ToList();

    //add new column to the header row
    lines[0] += ",Column 4";
    int index = 1;

    //add new column value for each row.
    lines.Skip(1).ToList().ForEach(line =>
    {
        //-1 for header
        lines[index] += "," + newColumnData[index - 1];
        index++;
    });
    //write the new content
    File.WriteAllLines(@"C:/CSV/test.csv", lines);
```

This however throws up an exception 
"index was out of range must be nonnegative and less than the size of the collection"

Any advice would be most welcome as always.

Comment: Why not use the CsvHelper library? [CsvHelper link](https://joshclose.github.io/CsvHelper/)

Comment: What's lines.Count?

Comment: Is there any possibility your data might have a new line in it? CSV can represent this by putting a field containing a new line between quotes. If you do have this scenario splitting the file into lines using File.ReadAllLines will not give you the desired result.

Comment: What's newColumnData.Count? Is it the one less than lines.Count?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why so many *materializations* `ReadAllLines()`, `.ToList()`? Why not just

```
String filePath = @"C:/CSV/test.csv";

var csv = File.ReadLines(filePath) // not AllLines
  .Select((line, index) => index == 0 
     ? line + ",Column 4"
     : line + "," + index.ToString())
  .ToList(); // we should write into the same file, that´s why we materialize

File.WriteAllLines(filePath, csv);
```

Comment: This is the real answer.  Nice use of the index provided with select, combined with the ternary operator.  If there is an array newColumnData with a new value for each line in the csv, this answer is exactly right.

Comment: this still throws up the Index was out of range, there is no data in the new column, (i assume this is why it is crashing) ie. the count for newColumn data is 1

Comment: @AgapwIesu: thank you! I see "...which will just count up the number of lines..." your suggestion - `index.ToString()` is all that required.

Comment: AgapwIesu, you are wonderful!! thank you very much. Thanks Dmitry, that is some great code there.

Answer (score 7):

You should not index inside the foreach.  The foreach gives you a line at a time.

```
lines.Skip(1).ToList().ForEach(line =>
{
    //-1 for header
    line += "," + newColumnData[index - 1];
    index++;
});
```

The lambda expression means: take each element in the list, and call it "line", and do what is inside the curly brackets to it.

Also, as I see it here, your newColumnData only seems to have one item in it, the string "D".  Yet you are indexing it as if there was one item in this list for each line in the csv file you read.  That too will cause an index out of range if your csv file has more than one line in it but... never mind, the more I think about it, the more you should just go with Dmitry Bychenko's answer.

Comment: hi @AgapwIesu I don't have an array of values, I would just want to fill each line of the new column with numbers, i.e. to count the number of lines e.g..

Comment: col1, col2, col3, col4 (new column)
data, data, data, 1
data, data, data, 2
etc etc

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that newColumnData does not have enough data in it. Try this which will give you an appropriate error message when this situation occurrs. Also you are going to get an error if the file is empty. Finally the solution you have is inefficient as it has to copy the string array returned from File.ReadAllLines into a list when there is no need to.

```
        List<string> newColumnData = new List<string>() { "D" };
        string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(@"C:/CSV/test.csv");

        if (lines.Length == 0)
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException("The file is empty");
        }

        //add new column to the header row
        lines[0] += ",Column 4";

        //add new column value for each row.
        for (int i = 1; i < lines.Length; i++)
        {
            int newColumnDataIndex = i - 1;
            if (newColumnDataIndex > newColumnData.Count)
            {
                throw new InvalidOperationException("Not enough data in newColumnData");
            }

            lines[i] += "," + newColumnData[newColumnDataIndex];
        }

        //write the new content
        File.WriteAllLines(@"C:/CSV/test.csv", lines);
```

Answer (score 0):

Without examining much more, I can tell you that you definitely have a challenge with the lambda you're using for the update:

```
    //add new column value for each row.
    lines.Skip(1).ToList().ForEach(line =>
    {
        //-1 for header
        lines[index] += "," + newColumnData[index - 1];
        index++;
    });
```

This would make more sense to me:

```
    //add new column value for each row.
    lines.Skip(1).ToList().ForEach(line =>
    {
        line += "," + newColumnData[++index - 2];
    });
```

The `lines[index]` part doesn't make sense in a `ForEach` since you're looping through each line separately.