# Wondering how to add a new column to a CSV file with existing code (C#)

Tags: c#, .net-core

I have some code shown below where I'm reading from a file, writing it out on a console app, then writing it to the same file where the values are reordered. My current problem now is adding a new column (4th column), and writing the reordered data to that new column all while keeping the old data in it's original format.

I'm opening the CSV in Excel if that's of any consequence.

I've tried the answers in these StackOverflow and ASP forum website questions, but I guess the big issue here is where to position the code.

[c# Add a Column to end of CSV file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37863108/c-sharp-add-a-column-to-end-of-csv-file)

https://forums.asp.net/t/1979251.aspx?Add+new+column+in+existing+CSV+file+using+C+

```
    var runProg = true;

    var filePath = @"C:\csharp\CSVFile.csv";

    List<Contact> contacts = new List<Contact>(); 

    var csv = File.ReadAllLines(filePath).ToList();

    File.WriteAllLines(filePath, csv);

    while (runProg)
    {
        foreach (var line in csv) 
        {
            var entries = line.Split(',');

            Contact newContact = new Contact();

            newContact.FirstName = entries[0];
            newContact.LastName = entries[1];
            newContact.EmailAddress = entries[2];

            if (entries.Length != (3))
            {
                throw new Exception("Invalid number of items in list.");
            }

            contacts.Add(newContact);

        }

        Console.WriteLine("Read from CSV file.");
        foreach (var contact in contacts)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"{contact.FirstName}-{contact.LastName}-{contact.EmailAddress}");
        }

        List<string> output = new List<string>();

        foreach (var contact in contacts)
        {
            output.Add($"{contact.FirstName}-{contact.EmailAddress}-{contact.LastName}");
        }

        Console.WriteLine("Writing to CSV file.");

        File.WriteAllLines(filePath, output);

        Console.WriteLine("All entries written...Q program?");
        var loop = Console.ReadLine();

        if (loop == "Q")
        {
            runProg = false;
        }
```

I need is to insert code that will allow me to create a new column to write the reordered data to. 
The main Exception that is thrown when I try to add test code is System.IndexOutOfRangeException: Index was outside the bounds of the array. 
Not sure how to expand that (if that's even possible).

Answer (score 1):

The first time you read the file you're splitting each line on comma ",", but then you rewrite all the lines using dash "-" as the delimiter.  So the next time you try to read the file in, and again try to split on comma, it will only return an array of length 1 (one), because there are no commas present, and then the lines setting the values for "newContact" will give the indicated exception.

Change:

```
output.Add($"{contact.FirstName}-{contact.EmailAddress}-{contact.LastName}");
```

To:

```
output.Add($"{contact.FirstName},{contact.EmailAddress},{contact.LastName}");
```

**BUT**, you've switched the order of the last name and the email address so on subsequent reads those values are going to be populated into the wrong instance fields.

You can add in more columns by simply changing the `output.Add()` line, and separating all columns with a comma.

Final note...move the `if (entries.Length != (3))` line up to after the `Split()` call and **before** you try to access the array with hard-coded indices.

Comment: Your suggestions paid off! Thank you for the response. I'm pretty much a rookie at programming (as I'm sure you've guessed), thus, the variety of questions.